# Bootstrap columns work in IE and edge (columns appear side by side), but not in chrome (columns stack vertically)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

i've just started learning web dev with bootstrap.

I'm running into a problem i don't understand. When i view my project in IE or edge everything looks as expected (columns side by side):
Internet explorer vs chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWe8Y.png

I've checked whether this is due to screen size, but the columns remain stacked vertically no matter how big I make the screen in chrome.

index.html code:

```css
    .customDiv{
        margin:3px;
        min-height:300px;
        background-color:silver;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:large;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS --><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CustomStyles.css">
    
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!--Columns must always be the children of a row class-->
                <div class="col-2">
                    <!--Content must always be inside a col class-->
                    <div class="customDiv">Column 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="customDiv">Column 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="customDiv">Column 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Would really appreciate any help. Been stuck on this for a while and I can't find anyone else who has had this exact problem.

Comment: your first col has a class definition error: <div class="col-2">

Comment: use either `col` or `col-md-2` instead of `col-2` here ;)

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, but my bad, that was just a typo i forgot to fix before posting the question after experimenting to try and fix the problem. Changed to col-md-2, but the problem persists. @G-Cyrillus

Comment: Would I be correct that your initial layout is done using IE or Edge?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by initial layout? Using microsoft visual studio as ide, and from there simply viewing in browser.

Comment: Which browser are you then viewing in as your first check of correctness?

Comment: @Rob Originally the default setting in visual studio was edge. So that would be edge. But changed to chrome soon after starting the project.

Comment: So this would be the current, chromium-based version of Edge? My point is, one should never, EVER use ANY Microsoft browser to check how things should work except the current version of Edge which, to a point, is good enough.

Comment: By chrome, i mean google chrome

Comment: @Rob Any suggestions given the browser i am referring to is google chrome?